# array_unique() not functioning as it should?

Tags: php, arrays, array-unique

I have an array in variable `$votes`. `print_r($votes)` gives us:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 )
```

So we have three values, all of which are set to `1`.

Now, I want to make the array only have unique values, meaning that if there are three values that match `1`, then remove two of them.

To achieve this, I tried `array_unique($votes);` but it did not remove any values. Why?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to assign the output of `array_unique` to the array again like this:

```
$votes = array_unique($votes);
```

As a reference you can look at the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

And a quote from there:

> Takes an input array and returns a new array without duplicate values.

Comment: Kindly point a gun right to my head. Thanks. I just realised this mistake :)

Comment: Question, how did you realise I made this mistake? I can't see how you noticed this via my question. Good catch nonetheless.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Because you wrote: *I tried array_unique($votes);* So without the assignment

Comment: In that case, just approve the answer.

Comment: @Sylverdrag There is a 15 min delay before I can mark it as fixed :)